# Proof in Rudin, real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, radicals

There is one thing in this proof I do not get. Why can he say that $k < y$?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just prove it? You are given precisely what $k$ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
k = \frac{y^n - x}{ny^{n-1}} = \frac 1n y - \frac{x}{ny^{n-1}} < \frac 1n y \leq y
$$

Comment: Well, $n$ can be $1.$

Comment: Doesn't matter, $x$ is positive.

Comment: I refer only to the last strict inequality.

Comment: @mfl fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You know that $$k=\frac{y^n-x}{ny^{n-1}}.$$

Then you can write it as: $$=\frac{y^n}{ny^{n-1}}-\frac{x}{ny^{n-1}}$$

Now, using $x>0$, $y>0$, $n>0$, the second term must be positive, thus you have the inequalities: $$<\frac{y^n}{ny^{n-1}}\leq\frac{y}{n}\leq y.$$

Using this chain of equalities/indequalities you have $k< y$.